# Create matrix using comprehension in julia

Tags: matrix, julia, list-comprehension

I want to create a diagonal matrix whose diagonals are powers of 1/2. I know I could do:

```
A = Diagonal(1, 1/2, 1/2^2, ..., 1/2^10)
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do this using a comprehension, something like this:

```
A = Diagonal((1/2)^x for x=[0:10])
```

Comment: Be aware that `[0:10]` is _very_ different from `1:10`. You want the latter, _not_ the former, which is a vector with only a single element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Diagonal`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/#LinearAlgebra.Diagonal) constructor takes the diagonal as a vector for input, so just use a regular [vector comprehension](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#man-comprehensions):

```
julia> using LinearAlgebra

julia> Diagonal([1/2^i for i in 0:4])
5×5 Diagonal{Float64, Vector{Float64}}:
 1.0   ⋅    ⋅     ⋅      ⋅ 
  ⋅   0.5   ⋅     ⋅      ⋅ 
  ⋅    ⋅   0.25   ⋅      ⋅ 
  ⋅    ⋅    ⋅    0.125   ⋅ 
  ⋅    ⋅    ⋅     ⋅     0.0625
```

Comment: Or `(1/2) .^ (0:10)`. (But boy, I had a hard time making sense of the behaviour of that when you leave out any of its parentheses...)

Comment: Note: a subtle difference between this and the second code block in the question is that here 2 is raised to the power first, so Integer limitations apply, whereas with `(1/2)^x`, 1/2 becomes 0.5 first, so floating point limitations apply. Eg: `1/2^65 == Inf`, and `(1/2)^65 == 2.710505431213761e-20`.